# Java Hibernate ajuda

Tags: java, hibernate

Persistence.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
  http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>Funcionario.Funcionario</class>
    <class>Estoque.Estoque</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

EntityManagerProvider.java

```js
public class EntityManagerProvider {
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = null;
    private static EntityManager em = null; 
    private EntityManagerProvider() { 
    } 
    public static EntityManagerFactory getEMF() { 
        if (getEmf() == null) { 
            Properties prop = new Properties(); 
            prop.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost/Mercado"); 
            prop.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
            prop.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "root"); 
            prop.setProperty("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "root"); 
            setEmf(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PU", prop)); 
        } 
        return getEmf(); 
    } 
    public static EntityManager getEM() { 
        if (getEm() == null) { 
            setEm(getEMF().createEntityManager()); 
        } 
        return getEm(); 
    } 
}
```

FuncionarioDAO.java

```js
public class FuncionarioDAO {
    EntityManager em; 
    public FuncionarioDAO() { 
        em = EntityManagerProvider.getEM(); 
    } 
    public void salva(Funcionario f) { 
        em.getTransaction().begin(); 
        if (f.getCodigo()== 0) { 
            em.persist(f); 
        } else { 
            em.merge(f); 
        } 
        em.getTransaction().commit(); 
    } 
    public Funcionario localiza(int codigo) { 
        Funcionario f = em.find(Funcionario.class, codigo); 
        return f; 
    } 
    public void exclui(Funcionario f) { 
        em.getTransaction().begin(); 
        em.remove(f); 
        em.getTransaction().commit(); 
    } 
    public List<Funcionario> pesquisa() { 
        Query q = em.createQuery("select f from Funcionario as f order by f.nome"); 
        List<Funcionario> lista = q.getResultList(); 
        return lista; 
    } 
    public List<Funcionario> pesquisa(String nome) { 
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select * from funcionario where nome like ? order by nome", Funcionario.class); 
        q.setParameter(1, '%' + nome + '%'); 
        List<Funcionario> lista = q.getResultList(); 
        return lista; 
    }    
    
}
```

ERRO

```css
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named PU
 at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
 at persistencia.EntityManagerProvider.getEMF(EntityManagerProvider.java:27)
 at persistencia.EntityManagerProvider.getEM(EntityManagerProvider.java:33)
 at persistencia.FuncionarioDAO.<init>(FuncionarioDAO.java:18)
 at Tela.Gerenciar.<init>(Gerenciar.java:23)
 at Tela.Gerenciar$10.run(Gerenciar.java:383)
 at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Como está o classpath do seu projeto?. O eclipselink.jar esta nele?

Comment: voce deveria ter colocado as propriedades no arquivo persistence, nao diretamente no codigo, assim voce esta quebrando varios padroes de projeto.